# как правильно выбрать один из классов

Tags: javascript, jquery

вот небольшой код  и функции  как мне правильно записать что именно этот див с классом .userStatus нужно окрасить в голубой(код дает запросы на стрим и если пипл офлайн то его поле нужно закрасить) (нужно наверно использовать this но как правильно)

```
$.getJSON(getUrl("streams", chan), function(data) {
        if (data.stream !== null) {
             $(".userStatus").css("border-left","10px solid MediumSpringGreen");
            }
        else if (data.stream === null) {
            $(".userStatus").css("border-right", "10px solid grey");
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используется `eq(index)` где `index` все элементы начиная с нуля. `eq(0)` выберет первый элемент. А например `eq(2)` выберет третий. Логино предположить что `index = номерЭлемента - 1`

```js
$(".userStatus").eq(2).css("background", "blue");
$(".userStatus").eq(2).css("border", "1px solid #0013BE");
```

```css
.userStatus {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#FF5328;
display:inline-block;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #DE4823;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="userStatus"></div>
<div class="userStatus"></div>
<div class="userStatus"></div>
<div class="userStatus"></div>
<div class="userStatus"></div>
```

Comment: нужно тогда eq(data.stream._id)

Comment: вот весь код https://codepen.io/OksanaKaragicheva/pen/PjBdJx?editors=1111 он маленький но правка по вашему чет не получается